The application cannot access the iOS keychain for the application publisher (the TeamId is null). What could be the problem?
Hello I am created IdentityClient
`     public MSAuthenticator()
        {
            IdentityClient = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                    .CreateWithApplicationOptions(appOptions)
                    .WithExperimentalFeatures(true)
                    .WithLogging(_logger)
                    .WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup("com.microsoft.adalcache")
                    .Build();
        }`

And added custom Entitlements.plist to .csproj
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.microsoft.adalcache</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>`

error_code = cannot_access_publisher_keychain
I still get an error on VS Code, please help!!!
The application cannot access the iOS keychain for the application publisher (the TeamId is null). This is needed to enable Single Sign On between applications of the same publisher. This is an iOS configuration issue. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-enable-keychain-access for more details on enabling keychain access.

Not sure, but I think you are missing the application identifier here .WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup("com.microsoft.adalcache")

Clearing the cache in Visual Code solved my problem

Clearing the cache in Visual Code solved my problem
